# How to Debug other project than "main"?

Tags: json, node.js, debugging, configuration, visual-studio-code

Using Visual Studio Code, I have two directories in my workspace (both node.js projects), but I can only launch one of them. The launch.json file exists in both folders, but only the first is available in debug menu. The launch.json files looks like that:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\app.js",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I start debugging the second folder of my workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the first folder from the workspace, started the only project left, then added the removed folder again. Now I have both projects in the launch configurations.

Answer (score 1):

I have found two solutions. Both involve editing your *.code-workspace file.

1. As OP found, you can reorder the folders. In the *.code-workspace file, place the folder with the desired launch.json at the top of the list of folders.

   ```
   "folders": [
     {
       "path": "..\\ProjectWithLaunchJson"
     },
     {
       "path": "..\\MyOtherProject"
     }
   ]
   ```
2. Alternatively, you can include the launch configuration in the *.code-workspace file.

   ```
   "folders": [
       :
       :
   ],
   "settings": {
     "launch": {
       "configurations": [
           {
              <copy your launch.json's configuration into here>
           }
       ]
     }
   }
   ```

   YMMV. I had to tweak the path to the executable. And I had to remove the preLaunchTask property since VS Code could not find the Task. VS Code's support for this will likely evolve.